# Magento 2.09 PayPal Pro Transaction Hangs

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I've tried to setup PayPal Pro on Magento 2.09 version. The redirects to PayPal site works, but when I enter the credit card information on the website and then hit submit, it hangs there with the wheel spinning and it says your card was declined. Is there a specific way to setup PayPal Pro on Magento 2.09? Both on Magento and in PayPal Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade Magento to version 2.1. There are many bugs resolved from 2.09.